# Upper bound for infinite sum

Tags: summation, power-series

Let $x \in (0,1)$, I need to find an upper bound (as good as possible) for the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n  n^k,$$
where $k$ is a natural number larger or equal than $2$, i.e., $k=2,3,4,\dots$.

My try: I know how to do it for $k=1$:
$$x^n(n+1)=(x^{n+1})'$$
and I suppose that something similar works for the rest of $k\ge2$. For instance, if $n>k$
$$\frac{d^k}{dx^k}(x^n)=n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdots (n-k)x^{n-k-1}\le n^kx^{n-k-1}.$$

But, then I am getting confused and I cannot get a clean way to finish this.

Edit: Also, I was told that for $k=4$, it holds that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n n^4\le \frac{24}{x^3(1-x)}$$ but I don't know how to verify this.

Edit2: So, assuming that the above is correct, is there a way to prove the conjecture that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n n^k\le \frac{k!}{x^{k-1}(1-x)}?$$

Comment: Are you familiar with *polylogarithms* ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No, but I will check it on Wikipedia, it looks relevant. Thank you.

Comment: What is $24$ ? Think about it

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, that is $4\times 3\times 2$. Now, on the Wikipedia page, I find an exact formula for the sum, and actually I get an even better bound (I mean, I get the exact value of the sum)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici So, is it valid to conlude that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n n^k\le \frac{k!}{x^{k-1}(1-x)}?$$ Thank you.

Comment: I saw that in one of your earlier edit, you had a correct upper bound. What led you to believe that the current, incorrect version of the bound to hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** The proposed inequality **cannot be true for $k > 0$**, because

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^k x^n \sim \frac{k!}{(1-x)^{k+1}} \quad \text{as} \quad x \to 1^- $$

and hence the sum will blow up at a speed of $(1-x)^{-k-1}$.

**2.** What is true is

$$ \frac{k!x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}} \leq  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^k x^n \leq \frac{k!}{(1-x)^{k+1}} $$

This will be particularly useful when $x$ is close to $1$, and also shows that the upper bound correctly captures the leading term in the Laurent expansion of the sum about $x = 1$.

Or, extending @Sungjin Kim's answer, we have the following identities

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^k x^n
&= \sum_{j=0}^{k} \biggl\{ {k \atop j} \biggr\}  \frac{j! x^j}{(1-x)^{j+1}} \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^{j-k} \biggl\{ {k + 1 \atop j + 1} \biggr\} \frac{j!}{(1-x)^{j+1}},
\end{align*}

where $\bigl\{{k \atop j}\bigr\}$ is the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). Again, note that the second line is precisely the Laurent expansion of the series about $x = 1$, and the leading term is $\frac{k!}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$.

Yet another representation is

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^k x^n = \frac{x A_n(x)}{(1-x)^{n+1}}, $$

where $A_n(x)$ is the [Eulerian polynomials](http://oeis.org/wiki/Eulerian_polynomials). In short, there are ways to expand the infinite series in the form of a combinatorial sum, but I am not sure if this helps in your situation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am aware of the possible expansions with Stirling numbers or Euler polynomials. But the upper (and lower) bounds that you give in the beginning do help in my situation because they are simple and handy to use. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We can write the sum as a finite sum using Stirling numbers of the second kind. We have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^nn^k=\frac1{1-x}\sum_{m=1}^k S(k,m)m! \left(\frac x{1-x}\right)^m.
$$
We obtain an upper bound by applying an upper bound of Stirling numbers ($S(k,m)\leq \frac12 \binom km m^{k-m}$ if $k\ge 2$, $m\le k-1$. If $k\geq 2$,
$$
\frac1{1-x}\sum_{m=1}^k S(k,m)m! \left(\frac x{1-x}\right)^m\leq \frac1{1-x}\sum_{m=1}^{k-1} \frac12 \binom km m! m^{k-m}\left(\frac x{1-x}\right)^m+\frac1{1-x} k! \left(\frac x{1-x}\right)^k.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. The upper bound is useful. Is there a way (that you are aware of) to upper bound the sum that appears on the right hand side? I prefer to have a simpler bound (even if I sacrifice some accuracy). Thank you (anyway)!

Comment: I am not aware of a better bound. This is just a try, as the binomial coefficients are simpler than Stirling numbers.